# XSL Transformation: Count Elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, transformation

I need to detect the first title element and print out a special comment before this first title element.

```
<xsl:template match="title[string-length(.) &gt; 0]" mode="content">
    <xsl:comment>%title id="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"%</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

I can detect these title elements, but what i've got to do to count and get this special comment before the first title element?

EDIT:
Thanks for the comments, but i can't get it to work unfortunatly. So additionally i add the XML source here, maybe someone could point me to en elegant solution?

```
<body id="EL_bodyN10001"><text id="EL_textN10001"><page id="EL_pageN10004"><p id="EL_pN10006"></p><p id="EL_pN10012">lorem ipsum dolor sit</p><p id="EL_pN10045">msdfsdkfh sdfsfksd sfsdfsdfsdfdsfh <strong id="EL_strongN1004C">LOREM IPSUM</strong>. lorem aklsjd asda sdasjdlkjaksld</p>
<title id="EL_titleN10001">my first title here</title>
<subheading id="EL_subheadingN1006E" level="1">MY FIRST SUBHEADING</subheading><p id="EL_pN10075">sdfjlksjfsjdf sfsjfljsdf sfklöskdfö sdfölksföksölf sdfksfk</p><p id="EL_pN10084">tzputozu lultpülupützu tultlutzulztu wewe rrtrt.</p><title id="EL_titleN10001">my second title</title><subheading id="EL_subheadingN100D9" level="1">THIS IS MY SECONT SUBHEADING</subheading><p id="EL_pN100E0">this is another senseless paragraph test.</p></page></text></body>
```

Comment: Are all `title` elements siblings of the same parent? Then `match="title[normalize-space()][1]"` suffices. Or you could check there is no `preceding::title`.

Comment: Yes, the elements are alle siblings of the same parent.
Thanks for the hint. I tried it this way:
  <xsl:template match="title[string-length(.) &gt; 0]" mode="content">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="title[normalize-space()][1]">
    <xsl:comment>XXX FIRST %title id="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"%</xsl:comment>
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:comment>%title id="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"%</xsl:comment>
   </xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

Doesn't work and i don't know why

Comment: What are you counting?

Comment: I try to count the title element with pos() but the first occurance says pos = 7, the socond pos=15..there must be another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally the solution was using:

```
<xsl:variable name="subHeadingPos" select="count(./preceding-sibling::subheading)+1"/>
```

Thanks to you, guys

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<xsl:template match="title[string-length(.) &gt; 0][1]" mode="content">
<xsl:comment>XXX FIRST %title id="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"%</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>`

then write a second template `match="title[string-length(.) &gt; 0][position() > 1]"` with the other content.